# Gnome Shell installation problems in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 and installed gnome shell for looks.. For complete gnome experience I removed ubuntu settings using terminal and then installed gnome shell and restarted.. Now my display is showing a black screen with crossed cursor.. I thought to format my system but I have installed too many packages and I don't want to lose them. What should I do? Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This command will delete your configuration files. It will reset all the settings. **You will not be able to undo this!**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run these commands:

- For Gnome 2

  ```
  rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
  ```
- For Gnome 3

  ```
  rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
  ```

Comment: But sir all is showing is black screen can't open terminal

Comment: Use `ctrl+alt+f1` enter username and password and then run this command

Comment: Nothing happened where am i mistaking. Says abc@abc-desktop: are there spaces between dots or any other comand to get old ubuntu setting's package back as i had commanded sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-settings

Comment: just copy paste the commands and it should reset all your gnome settings..

Answer (score 0):

solved using terminal and giving command,

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

By this way i got the recent gnome setting which was not deleted by the system just removed then using sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktops.but still don't know how to exit terminal after pressing <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> first time used this command thanks for the suggestion anyway